# white space on top of UITabBarController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

i can't get rid of white space on top of my view. This only happens when I want to use navigation controller.

```
let viewController = ViewController()
let navController =  UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Might want to post a pic of it

Answer (score 1):

In your navController, add the following line in the viewWillAppear method.

```
navC.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

A navigation controller adds a navigation bar by default on all its child view controllers. If you want the navigation bar to be hidden. We need to do it explicitly in each child view controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Storyboard: Attribute Inspector > uncheck Adjust Scroll View Inset. 
Or set programmatically:
`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

[image]